# Openerp user menus

Tags: odoo

In openerp web module menus visibility are allowed on group.

Is there any way we can switch it to depending on users.

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 3):

Without modifying the framework, no.

But you can create a group for every user.

Comment: Can you tell me how openerp web framework renders the menu items ?

Answer (score 1):

Groups can be created from the interface using menu `Administration -> Users -> Groups`.

And users can be added from `Administration -> Users -> User`

Answer (score 0):

You have to create group for the each user. Then you can give that group to menus.